# New Gold Badge "Activist"

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Similar to the silver badge "Yearling"(Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation); this gold badge is earned if "Active for one year, earning at least 2000 reputation".

Comment: Too easy for a gold badge.

Comment: Yeah, I would bump it to 10 years, at least.

Comment: @DanielDaranas: To struggle for 1 complete year is not easy in my opinion :)

Comment: Consider that in a year there are ~240 work days (excluding weekends/holidays) and that the rep cap is 200 per day on upvotes. That translates to 48,000 rep a year for someone _really_ active. 2000 rep is achievable in **10 days**.

Comment: @Aditya 2,000 is too easy a threshold to give a golden badge. Thousands of users have this reputation over a year. This would result in lots of new gold badges.

Comment: @Oded how the heck do you get 200 rep in one day? The most I can get is about 2...

Comment: @Xarcell - 20 upvotes on answers. 40 on questions. Or any combination. Ask Jon Skeet how he does it ;)

Comment: @DanielDaranas Not everyone gets 200 rep everyday... Heck, I have never Mortarboarded in the last 4.5 months I have been active on SE... If you compare it with over activities like raising flags, reviewing stuff - I think 2000-3000 rep is just about correct... We have 1 year to balance it out...

Comment: @Oded: 2000 rep is *achievable* in far less than 10 days. It's achievable just in *votes* in 10 days...

Comment: Bump it to 20000, and that's a gold badge.

Comment: Looking at the SO leagues, last year ~320 users received 20000+ rep for 2012.

Comment: Well, yes. Didn't include bounties, accepted answers etc, @Jon

Comment: @JonSkeet yes it *is* achievable, but it's not exactly easy for most users. If you look at the user base there are over a 120,000 people who have more then 200 rep but only 22,000 that have more then 2000 rep. Maybe bump the requirement up to 3000 if your worried about it. It would then only apply to less then 10% of active users. That doesn't sound so unreasonable

Comment: I think 2000 is a bit easy if you are even just a "medium" level of activeness. I have been a member for 85 days and have ~1350 on SO and I would consider myself "mediumly" active... It might be a great idea, but 2000 is just too low I think.

Comment: Sorry but -1 in its current form. Way too easy for a gold badge. I would change to "Active member for three years, earning at least 10000 reputation each year".

Comment: Also, aside from the bad pun, the name doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @ryan - I think you just proved the point that it needs to be higher than 2000. Look at the [gold badge distribution](http://stackoverflow.com/badges), they're pretty much all in the 100's or low 1000's, so saying that 22K users have 2K rep already means (from the precedent) we're setting the bar too low for a gold badge.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes - a good mixture of time/activity/rep. Not sure on the naming though.

Comment: @nickhar maybe simply "Persistent Member"? Not sure either, will leave that to the team if and when such badge will be considered.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Badges rewarded for reputation are unhelpful. Reputation is already prominently displayed on SE. Badges should be reserved for things that are helpful to the site but not directly rewarded with reputation.

edit to clarify: I consider reputation to be the primary measure of contribution to the site. I consider badges to be a secondary measure. Yes, I think reputation is helpful and should continue to be the primary measure of contribution. What I think is unhelpful is for badges to merely echo reputation gain.

I don't know the history or intention of badges like [mortarboard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/50/mortarboard).

Comment: You earn reputation by being helpful though...

Comment: Epic, Legendary, Motarboard, and Yearling are all badges that reward reputation gains. There *is* precedent for a badge that rewards reputation.

Comment: @Mike: Why do we need another one?

Comment: @Mike - They all reward being _active_ of the site, not so much reputation gains.

Comment: @Oded - They reward being active on the site *only by* earning rep, I can be very active on the site *without* hitting rep caps (edits, reviews, flags and comments).

Comment: @hammar - I'm not saying we do need another one. I'm saying that it's incorrect to say `"Badges should be reserved for things that are helpful to the site but not directly rewarded with reputation."` - if we say that then why are those badges I listed even present? We're saying earning rep doesn't directly help the site?

Comment: @Mike Who said that rep doesn't help the site?  Aaron said that rep already comes with it's own rewards and as such doesn't need yet another reason for people to earn it; they are already sufficiently motivated to earn rep based on the existing functionality.

Comment: @Servy - And yes, I agree with that statement. What I'm saying is that I read Aaron's answer: "Badges rewarded for reputation are unhelpful"; I infer from that that he feels one users rep isn't helpful to the community, you may or may not agree, but that's how I read it. As such, I'm saying SO *already has* badges that *only* are awarded by earning copious amounts of rep **because** rep helps the site. Thus, I don't understand/agree with Aaron's answer... now, if it was changed to say exactly what you did, then yes, I would agree with it.

Comment: `I infer from that that he feels one users rep isn't helpful to all`  But that's not infer-able from what he said.  *The badge* encouraging rep isn't helpful; that doesn't mean the rep itself isn't helpful, just that the *additional* badge for it isn't helpful.  This thread doesn't exist to debate if the existing badges should be removed (feel free to make a new question if you want to discuss that) but the fact that there are already a number of badges encouraging earning rep means that you can argue we don't need another; we already have them.

Comment: @Servy - Yes, I suppose put in the context of *only* this question, you are correct. Aaron, can you edit your answer to make the scope (new rep badges) clear so I can recast my vote?